# Is it safe to remove /usr/share/locale if 'locales' package is removed

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, locale

I'm trying to make a minimalistic Debian install for a low-mem VPS box. I'll be uninstalling the `locales` package, as there is no need for any kind of locale support for my purposes (only a few server programs, English only is perfectly enough).

My question is that **is it safe to remove the all the leftover file from `/usr/share/locale` after removing the `locales` package?**

Or are those files **required for anything else**?

I know that there are a few temporary `perl ... LC_ALL missing` kind of errors after removing the `locales` package, but it is normal and is fixed after the first reboot. My question about that if there is no `locales` package, is there any point in keeping the files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just removed the directory on a test-box here(tm), and didn't notice any issues. Reinstalling `locales` will re-create the directory.